# Dynamically creating variable in Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am planning to use `kthread_run` API in my kernel module.
As kthread_run, returns a `struct task_struct *`, which i want to store in a variable global across my module.
However, i want one thread each for a `cpu` and i obtain no of cpus using `num_online_cpus`.
However, when i write following code:

```
    //outside init_module function
    int cpus = num_online_cpus();
    static struct task_struct *my_tasks[cpus];  

    static int __init init_module(){
           for(int j = 0; j < cpus; ++j){
                  my_tasks[j] = kthread_run(...);  
           }  
    }
```

However, i get following error on this:
**error: variably modified ‘tasks’ at file scope**
How can i achieve this ???

Comment: Your loop variable is `j`, but the array subscript is `i`? Anyway, use `kmalloc`

Comment: I think the problem is declaring `*my_tasks[cpus]`. When using global variables, which by the way is usually a bad choice, the sizes of your arrays must be compile time constants.

Comment: @Miline: Thats exactly the point. But how can i declare the array with exact size as num_of_cpus ?

Comment: Dont create array. Create dynamic linked list of items with each node as `task_struct`

Comment: @Vikas, You have the answer already below. Try to invest your time into your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variables are actually one per cpu, you might want to use the per_cpu macros.  The gist is, you declare such a variable with:

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct, my_tasks);
```

and then access the variable using

```
get_cpu_var(my_tasks).foo = bar;
```

You can get more info at See http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-5 (or percpu.h) for more details.

Comment: That's good but not usable in my situation. I need to access all variables together in main process and then create threads for each.

Comment: You can access the variable of another cpu using `per_cpu`.  (i.e.:  `per_cpu(my_tasks, other_cpu).foo = bar`).